# Why i cant pass bundle from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I can't pass a Bundle or other thing from fragment to Activity. When I just try to navigate from fragment to Activity.class without pass anything it executes will and shows me other activity fine but when I try to pass the image through bundle it just restarts my app without showing another activity. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Logcat does not show any error.

MyFragment Activity--> I am passing bitarray when clicking on imageview

```
case R.id.pictureView:
            photo= Util.getBytes(bp);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ScaleImageViewActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putByteArray("image", photo);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
```

and my activity where i am getting the bunddle

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photoview);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    bundle.getByteArray("image");
    byte [] photo = bundle.getByteArray("image");
    Bitmap bp = Util.getImage(photo);
    ScaleImageView imageView = (ScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageZoom);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Comment: rather passing actual image bytes, I would suggest pass URI or file path to the activity and get the image from that URI.

Comment: if you can explain your answer with the code please? and the other thing is that I am looking for a solution why my app restarts in the above situation?

Comment: You are most likely passing too much data. There is a size limit (that I don't know by heart).

Comment: Logcat does not show me any message for size limit

Comment: _but when I try to pass the image through bundle it just restarts my app without showing another activity_ that means your app has been crashed. The error should be _NullPointerException_ or _Out Of Memory Exception_.

Comment: may be you are passing too large image in intent. intent have different limit in different version of android to pass data. see here https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit

Answer (score 2):

Do in this way. 
first put this code in your fragment.

```html
 iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        final byte[] photo = baos.toByteArray();

         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ScaleImageViewActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putByteArray("image", photo);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now in Your activity,put bellow code.

```html
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        bundle.getByteArray("image");
        byte [] photo = bundle.getByteArray("image");

        final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(),
                        image.getHeight(), false));
            }
        });
```